# jquery Select list not reflecting new items in UI

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to update a select list with an ajax call after clicking a checkbox. The call returns the expected list, items (the list of 'options' created below) looks as expected. Alert even reveals the value in distlist to be updated, but the UI just does not reflect this at all. The original list remains as the ony visible items. functionally it behaves as if the list has been updated.

```
$('#includeHistoricCheckbox').unbind('change').change(function () {
    var historic = false;
    if ($("#includeHistoricCheckbox").is(':checked'))
        historic = true;

    $.post('Search/UpdateDistrictList', { includeHistoric: historic }, function (data) {
        var $distList = $('#districtDropdown');

        var items = "<option value=\" |ALL| \" selected=\"selected\"> (all) </option>";
                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    items += "<option value=\"" + item + "\" selected=\"selected\">" + item + "</option>";
                });

        $distList.html(items);

                alert($distList.val());

    });
});
```

What am I missing? How do I forcibly refresh this? Oh, by the way this is j-query 1.7.1

**EDIT**

I missed closing bracket in my post.

Comment: Use a delegate instead of binding/unbinding => jquery `.on()`

Comment: @Satpal No, I am not.

Comment: @TimVermaelen Okay, this also fires as expected, what did I gain by doing this? I'm serious, what was the expected outcome?

Comment: `selected=\"selected\"` try removing this from each loop item.

Comment: @Jai Tried it, as per Rohan's answer. It demonstrates that the val is still getting correctly updated, but the display is not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#includeHistoricCheckbox').off('change').on('change', function () {
    var historic = this.checked; // true if checked, false if not
    $.post('Search/UpdateDistrictList', { includeHistoric: historic }, function (data) {
        var $distList = $('#districtDropdown');
        var items = "<option value=\" |ALL| \" selected=\"selected\"> (all) </option>";
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
             items += "<option value=\"" + item + "\">" + item + "</option>";
        });
        $distList.html(items);
        alert($distList.val());   
    });
}); // <---i think you missed this (closing of change event.)
```

---

As i found that you have missed the closing *(this might be during posting)* but yet you can make use of `this.checked` which returns `true||false` on `check||uncheck` and you can update to `on, off` instead of `unbind`.

Comment: I tried updating to on/off. Good suggestion on the this.checked, definitely a good simplification. The closing bracket was a stack overflow copy paste error unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `selected=\"selected\"` from your `list-items` and use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) and [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off) like

```
$('#includeHistoricCheckbox').off('change').on('change',function () {
    var historic = this.checked;// use this.checked it will return true/false
    $.post('Search/UpdateDistrictList',{ includeHistoric: historic },function (data){
        var $distList = $('#districtDropdown');
        var items = "<option value=\" |ALL| > (all) </option>";
        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            items += "<option value=\"" + item + "\" selected=\"selected\">" + item + "</option>";
        });    
        $distList.html(items);    
        alert($distList.val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still not updating the UI, though distList.val is empty, which it would be because there are no selected items.

Comment: Then check what you are getting in `data` variable in `console`.

Comment: Thats what I mean, alert, or console would be an empty list in your suggestion. If I leave selected in there, console/alert displayed the desired list, the UI did not reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing you code to use append

```
$('#includeHistoricCheckbox').unbind('change').change(function () {
    var historic = false;
    if ($("#includeHistoricCheckbox").is(':checked'))
        historic = true;

$.post('Search/UpdateDistrictList', { includeHistoric: historic }, function (data) {
    var $distList = $('#districtDropdown');

    var items = "<option value=\" |ALL| \" selected=\"selected\"> (all) </option>";
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                items += "<option value=\"" + item + "\" selected=\"selected\">" + item + "</option>";
            });

    $distList.append(items);//append used instead of .html() function

            alert($distList.val());

});
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, appending would add new items and I certainly want to replace the old

Comment: That being said, I still tried appending to no avail.